# Problem with matrix reshaping (probably trivial)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need a matrix that is derived in a YouTube video.
The error is certainly trivial, but mathematics was a long time ago for me.
The upper part of the picture is from a YouTube video, the lower part is mine.
The resulting 4x4 matrix didn't seem to be right. Can you see where I made the mistake?

[image: my calculation]